# Why does a compiler-generated IEnumerator<T> hold a reference to the instance that created it?

Tags: c#, .net, garbage-collection, ienumerable

While working on a project, I wrote an iterator block similar to the following:

```
public class Sequence<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    public T Head{get; private set;}
    public Sequence<T> Tail {get; private set;}

    public bool IsEmpty {get; private set;}

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        Sequence<T> collection = this;

        while (!collection.IsEmpty)
        {
            yield return collection.Head;
            collection = collection.Tail;
        }
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I expected that after the second call to `MoveNext`, the GC would be able to collect the original collection, since the iterator block no longer holds a reference to it, only its tail (as seen in `collection = collection.Tail`).

However, this did not happen. I discovered the compiler-generated `IEnumerator<T>` will *always* hold a reference to the instance of `Sequence<T>` that created it.

To prove this, I wrote the following iterator block and inspected the generated IL:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    yield return default(T);
}
```

To my surprise, the IL was equivalent to this:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    var enumerator = new CompilerGeneratedEnumerator();
    enumerator.this_field = this;
}
```

Verbatim:

```
.maxstack 2
.locals init (
    [0] class Sequences.Sequence`1/'<GetEnumerator>d__3'<!T>
)

IL_0000: ldc.i4.0
IL_0001: newobj instance void class Sequences.Sequence`1/'<GetEnumerator>d__3'<!T>::.ctor(int32)
IL_0006: stloc.0
IL_0007: ldloc.0
IL_0008: ldarg.0
IL_0009: stfld class Sequences.Sequence`1<!0> class Sequences.Sequence`1/'<GetEnumerator>d__3'<!T>::'<>4__this'
IL_000e: ldloc.0
IL_000f: ret
```

By looking at the IL for `<GetEnumerator>d__3`, it seems the `<>4__this` field is *never* accessed. **So why is it generated anyway? Why does the enumerator need to point to the instance of `Sequence<T>` that created it?**

I was able to get around this problem by writing my own `IEnumerator<T>`, but I'm still wondering why this happens in the first place.

---

If you want to compile this yourself, you can grab the project's source from here: 
https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences

And here's the original iterator block:

```
ISequence<T> sequence = this;

while (!sequence.IsEmpty)
{
    yield return sequence.Head;
    sequence = sequence.Tail;
}
```

Comment: It would really help if you'd give an example which compiled - that code won't, currently.

Comment: *most* iterators will need to reference members of the class that they're a part of, so its perhaps forgivable that the compiler doesn't perform special analysis to determine that, in some odd circumstances, `this` isn't made use of during iteration. You don't *have* to use an iterator to implement `IEnumerable<>`.

Comment: (Where "that code" is the first example. The second does, of course.)

Comment: @JonSkeet I've edited my post to make the sample code more similar to the original code. I've also added a link to the project's source code so you can compile it yourself if you want to. Thanks.

Comment: @dcastro: Well it still doesn't compile, which is frustrating - I shouldn't really need to fetch a whole project here... it can't be that hard to come up with a short but complete example. Hopefully my answer already addresses the cause in both cases though.

Comment: @JonSkeet It should compile now, sorry about that. And yes, it did, thanks :)

Comment: Much better, thanks :)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I agree.. I expected the enumerator to release the reference to `this` after the second iteration since it isn't used anymore, but perhaps I expected too much. Thanks

Comment: @dcastro: In order for the enumerator to "release" the reference to `this` after the second iteration, it would have to write a null into the backing field.  Such action would be helpful in this particular case, but would almost never be worth the time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Logically your first method *should* capture `this`. This line:

```
Sequence<T> collection = this;
```

... will only execute on the first call to `MoveNext()`, so it really does need to capture it, and it can only capture it in an instance variable in the generated code. The compiler *could* explicitly null it out after its final use, but usually that would just be wasteful.

Now your second case is more interesting. Yes, in order to complete the method it doesn't need a reference to `this` - but if you were in a debugger, and you had a breakpoint on the `yield return` statement, you would *expect* to be able to inspect `this`, as you're in an instance method. So at least in a build with debug information and no optimization, I think it's reasonable to include `this` as an instance variable. In an optimized build it would make sense not to capture `this` (and accept that if you're debugging a build not meant for debugging, there are some limitations) but I guess this is just an optimization the compiler authors didn't consider important.

Comment: I agree with you on all accounts. I overlooked the fact that the enumerator really *did* need a reference to this `this` on my first example, and perhaps I expected too much of the compiler. Assigning `null` to `<>4__this` after its last use isn't an obvious optimization.

Comment: @dcastro: If it's any consolation, I seem to remember that I found a rather more worrying memory leak a while ago... I can't remember the details, but there are some nasty situations. They may have been fixed in later releases.

Comment: It may be worth noting that the first time an iterator's `GetEnumerator()` method is called, it will return a reference to the iterator itself, cast to `IEnumerator<T>`.  This means the method's return type must implement both `IEnumerable<T>` and `IEnumerator<T>`; the fact that someone with a reference to the enumerator could call `IEnumerable<T>.GetEnumerator()` upon it means it must hold all the information necessary for that.

Comment: @supercat: That's true for an iterator method returning `IEnumerable<T>`, but in this case the method is only declared to return `IEnumerator<T>`, so the generated class *only* implements `IEnumerator<T>`/`IEnumerator`, not `IEnumerable<T>`/`IEnumerable`.

Comment: @JonSkeet: The compiler actually skips the generation of the `GetEnumerator` part in that case?  Interesting.  Capturing `this` is required regardless, however, in order to handle the first call to `MoveNext`, and there would generally be no reason for an iterator to spend time nulling it out afterward.  To really handle variable scopes properly would require creating additional temporary objects and adding an extra level of indirection.  Semantically-correct scoping wouldn't be impossible, but it would be expensive and seldom worth the cost.

Answer (score 1):

If it's important that the original item is GCable after iteration has moved on, you could implement an [`IEnumerator<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/78dfe2yb%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) yourself, rather than having the compiler generate one for you.

The following compiles, but could probably be improved:

```
public class MyCollection<T> : IEnumerable<T>
{
    private T Head;
    private MyCollection<T> Tail;
    private bool IsEmpty;

    private class ThisEnumerator : IEnumerator<T>
    {
        public ThisEnumerator(MyCollection<T> toIterate)
        {
            _innerCurrent = toIterate;
        }
        private MyCollection<T> _innerCurrent;
        private bool _hasMoved = false;
        public T Current
        {
            get
            {
                return _innerCurrent.Head;
            }
        }

        object IEnumerator.Current
        {
            get
            {
                return this.Current;
            }
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _innerCurrent = null;
        }

        public bool MoveNext()
        {
            if (_hasMoved)
            {
                _innerCurrent = _innerCurrent.Tail;
            }
            else
            {
                _hasMoved = true;
            }
            return !_innerCurrent.IsEmpty;
        }

        public void Reset()
        {
            throw new NotSupportedException();
        }
    }

    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new ThisEnumerator(this);
    }

    IEnumerator IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return this.GetEnumerator();
    }
}
```

As to the "why" question, as I indicated in a comment, I just think it's likely that most iterators (and `async` blocks, that share a lot of this machinery) *will* need to access `this`.

Comment: Thanks Damien. I did say in my post that I wrote [my own iterator](https://github.com/dcastro/Sequences/commit/766f1d2e44c13fb4eb6c26e7a9a468b94283975c) though, very similar to yours.